# How to keep a C# and C++ Project for JSON Message Serialization in sync?

Tags: c#, c++, json, serialization, .net-core

We are building a detached system of low-level C++ clients in the wild and a dotnet core 2.1 C# WebAPI.

Currently we've chosen to serialize message classes into JSON strings and send them over the wire and deserialize them back.

But this approach starts to become cumbersome, as these classes live independently. So changes to a C# message class breaks the serialization with the corresponding C++ message class and vice versa.

Is there some C#/C++ interoperability we could benefit from in this scenario?

Or are we left alone with managing the message class projects manually, so that no changes to only one side of the equation is allowed?

Comment: Create a git repo who's job it is to maintain a protocol buffers project which builds c++ and c# libraries encapsulating the same version of .proto sources. 
Link your c++ and c# projects against the 2 common libraries.

Comment: protobuf has binary and JSON serialization support https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

Comment: Thanks. This sounds like a reasonable solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by Richard Hodges:

> Create a git repo who's job it is to maintain a protocol buffers project which builds c++ and c# libraries encapsulating the same version of .proto sources. Link your c++ and c# projects against the 2 common libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently impossible to solve the renamed C# message class issue.
However here's one solution that you can leave a 'aliases' field in your JSON to indicate the original name of your JSON object, for example:

`{
    ALIASES: {
        message: {
            ALIASES: ["ORINGINAL_NAME_OF_FIELD_MESSAGE1", "ORIGINAL_NAME2", "ORIGINAL_NAME3"],
        },
        property: {
            ALIASES: ["OLD_PropertyName", "OldName"],
            some_string: ["old_Sub_PropertyName"],
            some_array: ["Old_array"]
            some_number: null
        }
    },
    message: "some messages here",
    property: {
        some_string: "VALUE",
        some_array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        some_number: 0
    }
}`

This JSON example gives a field of each Aliases of every properties used in JSON,you can always deserialise it correctly since you can know all former name of any nodes.

The only thing is to remember not to change the "ALIASES" node.

- This method requires a rewrite of your JSON `stringify` and `parse` functions.